# How to get length of array in SPL2 splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My splunk data looks like this

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "foo": []
}
```

sometimes foo is empty, and sometimes it has data in it.  I want to query for all the EMPTY using [SPL2](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/SearchReference/Built-inDataTypes#array).

I tried `foo=[]` and I tried `foo="[]"` but neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following syntax :

```
<your_search>
| where isnull('foo{}')
```